# Why is "Current Time" (slot) validating script logic when its interval is not contained within the deadline interval (as defined in script logic)?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli, transaction, slottime, posixtime

I have locked my "deadline" (which is set into the future) in "POSIXTime" to the On-Chain Datum of my contract.

To unlock it, I am using the "current time" (aka current slot) obtained via [cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 2] when drafting the unlocking transaction.

The slot is entered into transaction as "Invalid-before xxxxxxxx" command. Note: the xxxxxxxx is the current time slot at that moment of inquiry.

My script/contract logic mandates: **deadlineReached = from deadline `contains` (txInfoValidRange info)**

My understanding is that it should not be unlocking because the "current time (or slot)" interval is not contained within the future "deadline" interval locked in my datum.

Example:
deadline = 5
CurrentTime = 3

Since my deadline Interval (locked in datum) is in the future (as POSIXTime), **why am I able to unlock the above said UTxO using the current slot (as queried at the time of transaction submission)?**